# Android Canvas drawing clearing

Tags: android, canvas

I've a bit of an issue.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint); 
}
```

My canvas scope is local to just that draw method, but is being wrote to mBitmap. I know how to clear canvas inside there but it'd be pretty pointless. My question is how can I reset canvas from just touch event, or any sort of event in run time? Let me know if you need some more information

Thanks

edit: i was going to use a private variable to the class like doesScreenNeedClearing and have a listener set that, then in the ondraw have it question it but i don't think things like that should be going in onDraw, but i don't know maybe that's how people do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `canvas.drawColor()` method. You can easily just use `Color.BLACK` or `Color.WHITE` or every color you want.

Comment: Hey Warren. Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if you misunderstood my question but that wasn't what I was getting at. I want to use the  methods that you are writing, but outside the scope of 'draw'. Like some how passing the draw method a new canvas when something happens. Do you understand?

Comment: I think I found the answer now anyway, thanks. I just needed to use like     ((DrawingView)mView).clearView();

Comment: Passing a new Canvas will not work. You can't call onDraw() with a new Canvas by yourself. That will cause some serious issues. Beside that I did infact didn't get what you were trying to say, sorry. But I am glad you found a solution.